# Wordpress loop return value have no html

Tags: php, wordpress

I add shortcode to Wordpress theme functions.php file but have, a problem. This code "[logos]" return only:

http://mydomain.pl/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/file1.pnghttp://mydomain.pl/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/file2.pnghttp://mydomain.pl/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/file3.pnghttp://mydomain.pl/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/file4.png

form custom field, but do not return HTML code.

```
function subscribe_link_shortcode() {

    $html = '<div>
             <h3>' . $mastertitle . '</h3>
             <div class="cmsms_clients_slider" id="cmsms_clients_slider553e45022ef2d">

              <script>
                jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                  jQuery(\'#cmsms_clients_slider553e45022ef2d\').cmsmsClientsSlider({
                    sliderBlock : \'#cmsms_clients_slider553e45022ef2d\',
                    sliderItems : \'.cmsms_clients_items\',
                    clientsInPage : 5
                  });
                });
              </script>

              <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="cmsms_clients_slider_arrow_prev"></a>
              <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="cmsms_clients_slider_arrow_next"></a>
              <ul class="cmsms_clients_items" style="width: 1161px; margin-left: 0px;">
            ';

            // WP_Query arguments
            $args = array(
              'post_type' => array( 'logo' ),
            );

            // The Query
            $query = new WP_Query( $args );

            // The Loop
            if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
              while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
                $query->the_post();

                $html .= '<li class="cmsms_clients_item" style="width: 232px;">
                  <img width="165" src="' .the_field('obrazek_logo'). '" class="cmsms_clients_img cmsms_animated" style="height: auto;">
                </li>';
              }
            } else {
              // no posts found
            }

            // Restore original Post Data
            wp_reset_postdata();

            $html .= '
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>';
    ;

    return $html;
}
add_shortcode('logos', 'subscribe_link_shortcode');
```

Anyone know why?

Comment: I copied this to my local install. I couldn't completely replicate your issue but with your code I was about to output a <ul> with <li> items in it. Do you have any php or console errors. WP_Degug set to true?

I used <?php echo do_shortcode('[logos]');?> in a page template file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the above code, site must be blank screen, as there is string parsing error. However, I have changed code little bit. Please, try this.

```
$html =  '<div>
               <h3>' . $mastertitle . '</h3>
                   <div class="cmsms_clients_slider" id="cmsms_clients_slider553e45022ef2d">

                       <script>
                            jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                                        jQuery("#cmsms_clients_slider553e45022ef2d").cmsmsClientsSlider({
                                        sliderBlock : "#cmsms_clients_slider553e45022ef2d",
                                        sliderItems : ".cmsms_clients_items",
                                        clientsInPage : 5
                                      });
                                    });
                                  </script>

                                  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="cmsms_clients_slider_arrow_prev"></a>
                                  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="cmsms_clients_slider_arrow_next"></a>
                                  <ul class="cmsms_clients_items" style="width: 1161px; margin-left: 0px;">
                                  ';
```